# What are the values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the series $\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\alpha}} $ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What are the values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} $ for which the series $$ \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\alpha}} $$ converges?

I've used **Liebnitz Test** and proved that for all $\alpha \gt 0$ the series converges. Now for $\alpha \lt 0 \ $ I can sense that the sequence
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\alpha}}$$ becomes oscillatory but how do I formally prove that in this case the series diverges?

Comment: If the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $a_n\to 0$, when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes I wanted to try that but $(-1)^n$ is giving me trouble to find the limit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\alpha\leqslant0$, then$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^\alpha}\right|=n^{-\alpha}\geqslant1,$$since $-\alpha\geqslant0$. Therefore, you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^\alpha}=0$, and so your series diverges.